# Flutter can't detect connected device when flutter web is enabled

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

I am trying to make a Web project in flutter, but flutter web is not showing any connected devices.

[image]

Comment: What `flutter doctor --verbose` shows?

Comment: Might be a stupid question, but do you have either Chrome or Edge installed?

Comment: I have both Chome and Edge

Comment: I've edited the picture...now it has `flutter doctor --verbose`

Comment: Can it be the problem of directory?

Comment: Please don't post pictures of logs, paste them directly into the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`flutter config --enable-web` is not the only thing the [docs](https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/web) say to do before you can use flutter web. In my experience it's also necessary to switch to a flutter version that supports it, which is everything except the `stable` channel, to even see chrome show up as a device. Do the following to change channels.

```dart
flutter channel beta
flutter upgrade
```

Comment: *And don't forget to install the dart debug extension in chrome https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/dart-debug-extension/eljbmlghnomdjgdjmbdekegdkbabckhm

Comment: @ValdaXD Why is this necessary?

Comment: @ValdaXD That's not something that I've ever seen. I've been able to use and debug flutter web without anything additional.

Comment: Oh, i don't use chrome, i use opera. So that might be why(?), it just shows me a blank screen unless i install that extension. It makes sense for google to include flutter debugging in chrome out of the box

Comment: @ValdaXD That would make more sense. I've never seen that extension or had any problems without it. The docs only mention using chrome, so opera needing an extension seems likely.